# What is the query format for Terraform New Relic Workload resource

Tags: terraform, newrelic

What is the query format for Terraform New Relic Workload resource? I have the below resource specified in my `main.tf` file and I want to be able to get all the entities that have a specific label.

```
...

resource "newrelic_workload" "prod-app" {
  name       = "Prod App"
  account_id = <account id>

  entity_search_query {
    query = "label.STAGE = prod"
  }
}
```

However, it seems to throw this error:

```
Error: A downstream error occurred., [{"extensions":{},"message":"Search query \u003clabel.STAGE = 'prod'\u003e is invalid, response message is \u003cProvided filter: label.STAGE = 'prod' is not a valid NRQL query (You can't use field: label.STAGE, that is not defined in  schema.)\u003e"}]
```

There doesn't seem to be much info on the documentation other that it needs to be a valid NRQL query. The example seems to use `"name like 'Example application'"`
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/newrelic/newrelic/latest/docs/resources/workload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. Turns out that I was just referring to a key that doesn't exist.
It should be `tags.<tag key>` so `tags.label.STAGE`.

I noticed my mistake when I looked at the API behind the scenes. It uses the [NerdGraph API](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apis/nerdgraph/get-started/introduction-new-relic-nerdgraph) and the [Query entities](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apis/nerdgraph/examples/nerdgraph-entities-api-tutorial) section describes how to structure your query.